# Subclassing a dict or list

Tags: python, python-2.7, subclass

I am creating an object that I want to be -either- a dict or a list based on some condition. A basic version of what I am testing is as follows:

```
class MyClass(dict):
    def __init__(self, key, val, allowed):
        self.d = {}
        if key in allowed:
            self.d[key] = val
            super(MyClass, self).__init__(self.d)
        else:
            # I am a list and not a dict


obj = MyClass("a", "b", "abc")
```

I am wondering if this is possible AND if there is a better way to achieve similar results that is a "better coding practice."

(I do not want to do a pre-check to see if key is in allowed before object creation)

Comment: Why would you even want to do this in the first place? Types that alter  behaviour entirely are generally not very useful.

Comment: You can implement the [mutable mapping and sequence ABCs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.abc.html); there is a lot of overlap between the methods either type implements.

Comment: It's not that I necessarily want to do it, but I want to see if it can be done!

Comment: Yes, it can be done. Just implement the methods of both types.

Comment: Well, I could just override the __new__ method to conditionally return one of the two types too. No need to reinvent the wheel, right?

Comment: Then just use a *factory function*, one that returns an instance of one or another class based on conditionals. `__new__` is overkill there.